# Hibernate HQL for joining non-mapped tables

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have an entity called "Kurs":

```
@Entity
public class Kurs {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long kursId;
    private String name;
    //Accessors....
}
```

And also an entity called "Kategori":

```
@Entity
public class Kategori {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long kategoriId;
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable (name = "KursKategori", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "kategoriId")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "kursId")})
    private List<Kurs> kursList;
    // Accessors....
}
```

Now I'm building a `KursDao` that will have a method to fetch a list of `Kurs` by the `kategoriId`, but I'm unable to get the join to work for me.
Being used to SQL, I would normally think the query should be like this:

```
getHibernateTemplate().find("from Kurs as k INNER JOIN KursKategori kk ON k.kursId = kk.kursId AND kk.kategoriId = ?", kategoriId);
```

But this doesn't work and I can't get anything like this to work. I do not want to create a class of the `KursKategori` since it is only a mapping table anyway.
Is there a way to join the non-mapped table `KursKategori` to the mapped table `kurs` so that I will only get the `Kurs` that is in the correct `Kategori`?

Comment: What is the error that you get? How is your database deployed?

Comment: unexpected token: ON near line 1, column 67 [from no.dahlsdata.model.Kurs.Kurs as k INNER JOIN KursKategori kk ON k.kursId = kk.kursId AND kk.kategoriId = ?]

Comment: It doesnt like my ON keyword. I've also tried different variations. E.g. using old style joining (from kurs k, kurskategori kk where kk.kursId=k.kursId and kk.kategoriId = ?) but this just gives an error that kurskategori is not mapped. But i dont want to map kurskategori. I just want to join my kurs against it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In HQL you can only join on mapped relationships between entities. However, you have such a relationship, so that you can use it:

```
select kurs from Kategori kat join kat.kursList kurs where kat.kategoriId = ?
```

Comment: Lets assume you want to select _kat_ instead of _kurs_. This means you don't need to access the _kurs_ table but the generated sql query does include a join on that table. How can you prevent that? The query would only need the _kat_ table and the join table.

Answer (score 6):

[Since Hibernate 5.1](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/how-to-join-unrelated-entities/) you can JOIN mapped entities **without** association.

So, this should work now:

```
SELECT k from Kurs as k 
    JOIN KursKategori kk ON k.kursId = kk.kursId AND kk.kategoriId = ?
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a query like this and will work.

```
from Kurs k, KursKategori kk where k.kursId = kk.kursId AND kk.kategoriId = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
getHibernateTemplate().find("from Kurs as k INNER JOIN KursKategori kk ON k.kursId = kk.kursId AND kk.kategoriId = ?", kategoriId);
```

You cannot make HQL query on KursKategori , a table which is not mapped in hibernate..

Either you can run sql query through hibernate template or a query something like this

```
select kurs from kategori k join fetch k.kursList where k.kategoriId = ?
```